# Error running npm run unit in Vue.js (babel-preset-stage-2)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

I'm a starter with **Vue.js** and I was trying to make some simple tests with **Jest**, but since the install of Vue with Webpack (the first thing I did was try to run the script), I can't get to run the `npm test` script.

I tried some tutorials ([this](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/testing-single-file-components-with-jest.html) and [this](https://alexjover.com/blog/write-the-first-vue-js-component-unit-test-in-jest/)) to make it run, but I still got the errors.

I searched some issues on Github and it looks like a dependence error, so I tried to install a lot of **babel** dependencies, changed to everything I could find in the answers, deleted node_modules and installed again several times, but nothing seems to work.

The console log error:

```
Test suite failed to run

    Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In /home/.../node_modules/babel-preset-stage-2/lib/index.js

      at createDescriptor (node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:178:11)
      at items.map (node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:50)
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at createDescriptors (node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:29)
      at createPresetDescriptors (node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:101:10)
      at presets (node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:47:19)
      at mergeChainOpts (node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:320:26)
      at node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:283:7
      at buildRootChain (node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:120:22)
      at loadPrivatePartialConfig (node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/partial.js:85:55)

Running coverage on untested files...Failed to collect coverage from /home/.../src/utils/ma
ps.js
ERROR: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In /home/.../node_modules/babel-preset-stage-2/lib/index.js
STACK: Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In /home/.../node_modules/babel-preset-stage-2/lib/index.js
    at createDescriptor (/home/.../node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:178:11)
    at items.map (/home/.../node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:50)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at createDescriptors (/home/.../node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:29)
    at createPresetDescriptors (/home/.../node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:101:10)
    at presets (/home/.../node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:47:19)
    at mergeChainOpts (/home/.../node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:320:26)
    at /home/.../node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:283:7
    at buildRootChain (/home/.../node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:120:22)
    at loadPrivatePartialConfig (/home/.../node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/partial.js:85:55)
```

My `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "luiza-challenge",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This app makes calls from a API to request address info.",
  "author": "~",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "unit": "jest --config test/unit/jest.conf.js --coverage",
    "test": "npm run unit",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit",
    "build": "node build/build.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "^3.0.1",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-resource": "^1.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^1.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "eslint": "^4.15.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jest-serializer-vue": "^0.3.0",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "postcss-url": "^7.2.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "vue-jest": "^1.0.2",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.7",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

And my `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "modules": false,
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["> 1%", "last 2 versions", "not ie <= 8"]
      }
    }],
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-vue-jsx", "transform-runtime"],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": ["env", "stage-2"],
      "plugins": ["transform-vue-jsx", "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs", "dynamic-import-node"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a few tries, I get it. It was really an error of configuration, I was missing some arguments. With theses changes in **package.json** everything works perfectly:

```
"jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "vue"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.vue$": "vue-jest",
      ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|svg|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "jest-transform-stub",
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/(?!jest-test)"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
    },
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "jest-serializer-vue"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)|**/__tests__/*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
    ],
    "testURL": "http://localhost/",
    "watchPlugins": [
      "jest-watch-typeahead/filename",
      "jest-watch-typeahead/testname"
    ]
  }
```

If you're not using Vue, and testing with pure javascript, these line works just fine:

```
"jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json"
    ],
    "transform": {
      ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|svg|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "jest-transform-stub",
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/(?!jest-test)"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
    },
    "testMatch": [
      "**/tests/**/*.test.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)|**/__tests__/*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
    ],
    "testURL": "http://localhost/"
  }
```

If it still not working, tring configure **Babel** and run it with **Webpack**. I used this configuration in both cases and worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into vue-cli and see if the tests work on a new install, it looks like you have a Babel problem you are using old Babel 'babel-core'. If you want a quick way to get Vue up and running try codesandbox.io.

Also you might want to edit you post as you have posted your email in the package.json file

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have correctly installed babel. You must delete the node_modules folder and install the latest babel version runing `npm install` or `yarn install`. Then try to run `npm run unit` again. The best solution is using Vue CLI in this page you can find the vue babel configuration manual [Vue Babel config](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#global-cli-config). [Babel plugin on github](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-babel)